# Click on Expand and Collapse button using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a group where i have to select the Expand icon and then expand further. Example: Click on **User Directory** and then **"Native directory"**

[image]

I used class method to click on "User Directory", which worked fine. But not able to move further. I used Class method, as xpath, css selector did not work and there is no element ID.

```
a=[]
a=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("bi-tree-view-expand-icon")
a[0].click()
```

The only difference is saw was in image title - Expand and Collapse

**USER DIRECTORY html code**
[image]

**Native Directory html code**

[image]

**HTML code**

```
<div class="bi-tree-view-body-content" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 197px; height: 104px;"><table class="bi-tree-view-table" style="width: 197px;" cellspacing="0"><tbody class=" focused"><tr class=" selected lead" style="height: 18px;"><td style="width: 197px; padding-left: 3px;"><nobr><img title="Collapse" class="bi-tree-view-expand-icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.cgate.com/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree-view-minus.gif"><img class="icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.cgate.com/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree_folder_closed.gif">User Directories</nobr></td></tr><tr style="height: 18px;"><td style="width: 197px; padding-left: 22px;"><nobr><img title="Expand" class="bi-tree-view-expand-icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.cgate.com/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree-view-plus.gif"><img class="icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.cgate.com/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree_folder_closed.gif">Native Directory</nobr></td></tr><tr style="height: 18px;"><td style="width: 197px; padding-left: 22px;"><nobr><img title="Expand" class="bi-tree-view-expand-icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.cgate.com/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree-view-plus.gif"><img class="icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.cgate.com/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree_folder_closed.gif">Honeywell</nobr></td></tr><tr style="height: 18px;"><td style="width: 197px; padding-left: 3px;"><nobr><img title="Expand" class="bi-tree-view-expand-icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.cgate.com/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree-view-plus.gif"><img class="icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.cgate.com/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree_folder_closed.gif">Application Groups</nobr></td></tr><tr style="height: 18px;"><td style="width: 197px; padding-left: 3px;"><nobr><img title="Expand" class="bi-tree-view-expand-icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.cgate.com/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree-view-plus.gif"><img class="icon" alt="" src="https://hyperionqa24.cgate.com/workspace/cache/2020-02-16_11-33-04/bpmstatic/thirdparty/bindows/html/themes/Skyros/images/tree_folder_closed.gif">File System</nobr></td></tr><tr class="vertical-filler" style="height: 14px;"><td style="width: 197px;">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

**Using CSS selector:**
- User directory - `.selected > td:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(1)`
- Native directory - `.focused > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(1)`

Comment: If `a[0]` is User Directories, would `a[1]` not be Native Directory?

Comment: No, it is jumping to the next list.I.e application groups. Please see the image from the URL - https://www.google.com/search?q=fdmee+shared+service+native+directory&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev1&prmd=isnv&sxsrf=ACYBGNRk7FUyOm-IKL9kH5K_JPbDb4UwYw:1581952141642&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWytD77tjnAhVU4jgGHS0sDBUQ_AUoAXoECA0QAQ&biw=393&bih=682&dpr=2.75#imgrc=o4py8SzdLFPQ9M%3A

Comment: Can you paste the html code for the complete directory tree? Maybe a differently constructed `xpath` might help. Alternatively, debug and find out the contents of `a` to then choose the correct a[index].

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: We need more of the surrounding HTML for the expando toggles.

Comment: Have edited my question adding html code

Comment: Any luck on the above issue?